# Could not or failed to fetch _Jammy Jellyfish and Jammy security on Ubuntu 22.04 amd-64

Tags: apt, updates

Running `sudo apt update` on *Ubuntu 22.04 amd-64* outputs:

[image]

Opened *.../sources.lists* through *vim* and commented out the first line this way:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/ jammy main restricted
```

And then:

```
me@me:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for me: 

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      

Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]     

Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]   

Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [101 kB]

Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [305 kB]

Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]

Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,952 B]

Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.9 kB]

Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                         

Ign:10 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                 

Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                              

Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                              

Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease

Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease

  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (178.254.35.97), connection timed out

Ign:10 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Ign:10 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Err:10 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 172.217.17.46 443]

Fetched 658 kB in 1min 28s (7,499 B/s)         

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

18 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (178.254.35.97), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 172.217.17.46 443]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

me@me:~$
```

How to fix it to successfully update, please?

Comment: It looks like possibly a network issue but on a side note, please copy and paste the terminal output instead of posting a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Replaced the latter screenshot with output (but can't go back and do the same for the former). By the way, I can access internet on my Ubuntu (which is installed on VirtualBox on Windows 10).

Comment: Is virtualbox using bridged or NAT? It should be using bridged.

Comment: @mchid Yes, it's on NAT. Should I change it to *Bridged Adaptor*?
https://imgur.com/Blb0af5

Comment: Yes I think so probably. If that's the only bridged option then yes.